# What is the minimum convergence value, for $x>1$, of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^x}{x^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory

I am a Calculus 2 student in college and we are learning about the tests for series convergence. One specific question caught my attention. We were to find if the following series is convergent or divergent: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^9}{9^n}.$$ I found it to be convergent, but I wondered what it converged to (this was outside of the scope of my course) and by putting it into a calculator found it to be about 138.3667. I was curious about what if instead of 9, it were other numbers and made a table similar to this:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^x}{x^n}.$$

```
  x   f(x)      
 -2  -0.44841  
 -1  -0.69265  
  0  Divergent 
  1  Divergent 
  2   6.00000   
  3   4.12500   
  4   4.69136   
  5   6.90430
```

I was curious about how the function has a minimum between 2 and 4 and used a graphing calculator, Desmos, to see what that minimum is when $x$ is about 3.12 with is converging to about 4.113

[image: Screenshot of the Desmos graph]

I wanted to know if there was a closed form equation to the series for which I could take the derivative and set it to zero. I put the series was put into WolframAlpha; it outputted $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^x}{x^n} = \operatorname{Li}_{-x}(\frac{1}{x})$ when $|x|>1$ and $\operatorname{Li}_n(x)$ is the polylogarithm function. I realized I was getting over my head when I had no clue what a polylogarithm was and asked my Calc 2 instructor for help. Unfortunately, he said how he didn’t specialize in this kind of math called Analytic Number Theory. He asked some of his colleagues and none that he’d asked knew much about how to handle this. The only way I thing that was figured out was the derivative of the polylogarithm but for orders of numbers with absolute value less than 1; explicitly where the function diverged.

He got back to me a few days later and recommend to ask the question on Stack Exchange (wow, that’s here!). We both don’t even know if taking the derivative of the polylogarithm is the way to go. Nor do we know of any other closed form equations for the series. I know I can just simply get arbitrarily close enough by computer algorithms to find when the derivative of the original function, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^x}{x^n},$$ is 0, but I would really like to have an exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

The polylogarithm is defined

$$\operatorname{Li}_s(z)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{z^n}{n^s}$$

So, to get your function, you would need to take

$$\operatorname{Li}_{-z}(1/z)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{n^z}{z^n}$$

Comment: Would it be possible to take the derivative of that particular polylogarithm? My Calc 2 instructor found the derivative but only for positive orders

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the ratio test, it always converges for $|x| > 1$ and diverges for $|x| < 1$. When $x = 1$, if you write down, the series is the sum of $n$ that diverges and if $x = -1$, it converges by the alternating series test.